# Better way to schedule cron jobs based on job orders from php script

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, cron, scheduled-tasks

So I wrote simple video creator script in NodeJS.

It's running on scheduled cron job.

I have a panel written in PHP, user enter details and clicks "**Submit new Video Job**" Button.
This new job is saving to DB with **details, jobId and status="waiting"** data.

PHP API is responsible for returning **1 status at a time**, checks **status="waiting"** limits query to **1** then returns data with jobID when asked

Video Creation Script requests every x seconds to that API asks for new job is available.

It has 5 tasks.

available=true.

1. Check if new job order available **(With GET Request in every 20 seconds)**, if has new job;
   available=false
2. Get details (name, picture url, etc.)
3. Create video with details.
4. Upload Video to FTP
5. Post data to API to update details. And Mark that job as "done"

available=true;

These tasks are async so everytask has to be wait previous task to be done.

Right now, get or post requesting api if new job available in every 20 seconds (Time doesnt mattter)  **seems bad way to me.**

So any way / package / system to accomplish this behavior?

Code Example:

```js
const cron = require('node-cron');
let available=true;

var scheduler = cron.schedule(
    '*/20 * * * * *',
    () => {
        if (available) {
            makevideo();
        }
    },
    {
        scheduled: false,
        timezone: 'Europe/Istanbul',
    }
);


let makevideo = async () => {
    available = false;
    let {data} = await axios.get(
        'https://api/checkJob'
    );
    if (data == 0) {
        console.log('No Job');
        available = true;
    } else {
        let jobid = data.id;
    await createvideo();
    await sendToFTP();
    
        await axios.post('https://api/saveJob', {
            id: jobid,
            videoPath: 'somevideopath',
        });
        available = true;
    }
};
scheduler.start();
```

Comment: cron looks a bit overkill here because I bet the same could be done with `setInterval()`

Comment: What do you think is missing or wrong with the system? Maybe you can change the status of the video in the database with node.js. And is there any specific reason for calling `makeVideo()` function every x seconds?

Comment: shaedrich; Yeah it can be done with setInterval, but node-cron is better way to manage timings, and schedules. But thats not the point,;


And Murat; 

Creating GET request in every 20 seconds to server is wrong to me. Another way must be exists without requesting every x time. This creates bandwith on system and moreover can be faild sometimes. 
I am looking for Another way of communication with app and API.  Just when order created or some pooling maybe?

Comment: Instead of cron, you can use Queue (Redis). When user enter details and clicks "Submit new Video Job" Button, you insert data in database and insert a job in redis queue. Your redis queue worker/consumer, will get that Job, process it which you're currently doing through cron and api and once consumer finishes it job, updates the database at backend itself.

Comment: Another cool way you could achieve this is to join the script to a socket connection on the API. Then whenever a new video gets added it just pushes the details of this out via the socket, the script would receive this and act in realtime, or as close as. This would mean you would just have a script contstantly running all the time and would remove the need to have a cron ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is possible to use the database as a queue, it is commonly known as an anti-pattern (next to using the database for logging), and as you are looking for:

> So any way / package / system to accomplish this behavior?

I use the free-form of your question thanks to the placed bounty to suggest: [**Beanstalk**](https://beanstalkd.github.io).

> Beanstalk is a simple, fast work queue.
>
> Its interface is generic, but was originally designed for reducing the latency of page views in high-volume web applications by running time-consuming tasks asynchronously.

It has client libraries in the languages you mention in your question (and many more), is easy to develop with and to run in production.

Answer (score 2):

#### RabbitMQ is also a good queueing system.

**Why ?**

It's really well documented (examples for many languages including javascript & php).

[Tutorials](https://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html) are simple while they're exposing real use cases.

It has a REST API.

It ships with a monitoring UI.

---

**How to use it to solve your problem ?**

On the job producer side : send messages (jobs) to a queue by following [tutorial 1](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-php.html)

To consume jobs with your nodejs process : see RabbitMQ's [tutorial 2](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-javascript.html)

---

**Other suggestions :**

Use a prefetch value of 1 and publisher confirms so you can ensure that an instance of consumer will not receive messages while there's a job running.

Roadmap for a quick prototype : tutorial 1... then tutorial 2 x). After sending and receiving messages you can explore the options you can set on queues and messages

Nodejs package : http://www.squaremobius.net/amqp.node/

PHP package : https://github.com/php-amqplib/php-amqplib

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing in a very standard system design paradigm, done with Apache Kafka or any queue based implementation(ex, RabbitMQ). You can check out about Kafka/rabbitmq but basically Not going into details:

1. There is a central Queue.
2. When user submits a job the job gets added to the Queue.
3. The video processor runs indefinitely subscribing to the queue.

You can go ahead and look up : https://www.gentlydownthe.stream/ and you will recognize the similarities on what you are doing.

Here you don't need to `poll` yourself, you need to subscribe to an event and the other things will be managed by the respective queues.

Comment: What would you consider the most boring tech queue/worker system?

Comment: I only used RabbitMQ and Kafka, in that I thought rabbitmq was simpler cause Kafka had so many functions that we didn't use. No wonder big companies like linkedin, netflix, oracle uses kafka.

Comment: And anything in the boring tech area? Like simple, dumb and approved since a decade or two? Just the good stuff?

Comment: sorry don't have any idea. Worked with TIBCO though I dont know if it's boring or not but it was kinda weird.

Comment: TIBCO I don't know, but if you already say its weird ... perhaps not a recommendation of yours. I've suggested _Beanstalk_ .